# Pull a CSS value into a variable with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to pull a css value from a certain class on a page, so that i can assign that to other elements in various ways.

I have set up an example in jsfiddle, here I would like to somehow grab the background from

```
.box
```

and add it to the "bg" variable

http://jsfiddle.net/43kt7/

Comment: add a dual class one specific to it and one shared

Comment: I don't think this could work for me, as I would have the background color in a shared class, but what if I wanted that color to be a border color on another element?

Comment: you dont need jquery for this use see this and tell me if this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/yasinallana/43kt7/1/

Comment: There are few questions in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493449/copy-all-styles-from-one-element-to-another – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/6416527#6416527

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: how to get the background color code of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/jquery-how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element)

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a specific css value using jQuery is done use the [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function. To get the `background-color` value, you can use:

```
var bg = $( ".box" ).css( "background-color" );
```