# How to copy all user provided styles from one object to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

A question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493449/copy-all-styles-from-one-element-to-another) about how to copy css styles from one object to another. And the generally accepted answer was:

```
var p = document.getElementById("your_p_id");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "your div content";
div.style.cssText = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(p, "").cssText;
```

However, my situation is a bit different. I have a script that creates a `span` to presume a `select` tag, and then hides the `select`. This allows for easier CSS styling since I can style the `span` easier, relative to an adamant `select` tag.

When I use `cssText`, to copy any styles applied from the select to the span, it ends up looking like a select tag. Since all inbuilt styles are applied to the span as well rather than just the user input, then I have to override all these css properties by the dozens, which beats the purpose of having a span tag in the first place.

Is there a way to only copy the user provided styles rather than the entire stylesheet used to style an element?

Thus far, I have able to transfer applied styles by transferring the `class` and `id` from select to span, but my the challenge is getting styles directly applied on the `select` tag (ie. in the style/stylesheet, it reads: `select { blah : bloh;}`)

Comment: How are the user defined styles applied? Using a class? If yes then apply the same class

Comment: Do you need old browser support?

Comment: Do you want only styles from style attribute?

Comment: Extensive browser support is necessary if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function ApplyStyles(select, span) {
    var select = document.querySelector(select);
    var span = document.querySelector(span);
    var sheets = document.styleSheets;

    for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var rules = sheets[i].cssRules || sheets[i].rules;   
        for(var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
            var rule = rules[r];
            var selectorText = rule.selectorText;
            if(document.querySelector(selectorText) == select){
        for(var l = 0; l < rule.style.length; l++){
            span.style[rule.style[l]] = rule.style[rule.style[l]];
        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the function like this:

```
ApplyStyles("#selection", "#span");
```

Here's a JSFiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/rsLnaw56/2/

How this works is it finds all external styles applied to the `select` element and applies it to the `span` element.